# How to fix Windows 10 "The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors"?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, windows-10

#### Problem:

---

[image: Screenshot1]

- My laptop [Acer Aspire VN7-592G] doesn't have an optical drive, so Windows 8.1 was installed via an external DVD drive; upon finishing the installation, it was not removed as the first boot option in the BIOS and while I believe this is a non-issue, could this be the cause?

#### Chronology:

---

1. After installing Windows 8.1, I discovered this laptop's driver support is for Windows 10 only, and after upgrading to Windows 10, everything appeared fine
2. **1st Reboot:** Weird Windows 7 logo screen appeared, followed by the [BSOD](https://neosmart.net/wiki/your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired/) above 
    **2nd Reboot:** Windows 7 logo screen and BSOD 
    **3rd Reboot:** BSOD with error code`0xc000000f`:

   ```
   Your PC needs to be repaired

   File:   \boot\bcd
   Status: 0xc000000f
   Info:   The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.

   You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media.
   ```
3. I created a bootable USB to perform a clean install of Windows 10; everything went fine, reboot was okay, and I used the laptop for 12hrs before turning it off
4. Upon turning it on, the Windows 7 logo and BSOD were back with error `0xc000000f`
5. I used the bootable USB to run a quick repair and it booted to Windows 10 successfully

#### Questions:

---

1. Is this a hard drive error that can be fixed via Automatic Repair or should I use my warranty?
2. How can I permanently fix this issue so it doesn't occur again?
3. How do I check the health of my laptop's hardware, as Device Manager showed no issue before this error occured?

Comment: It sounds like you never formatted the HDD before installing Windows, so it's likely the boot partition has a BCD store for Windows 7 _(you should **always** format any used HDD/USB drive prior to use when received from a third party)_. As @kirit_vanani states in their answer, format the HDD in the Windows installer, which will resolve your issue, but outside of your specific situation, to fix a BCD store issue, boot to WinPE/WinRE _(WinPE: Windows install USB || WinRE: **Win**dows **Re**covery)_ and issue the following: `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD`, then reboot

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Don't use your HDD for booting your system, as you can make a bootable USB for loading any OS you want to boot
- Change the boot order, placing USB as first, then boot your system
- In the Windows installer, choose the option to format your old drive before starting the install

You can use different methods for USB boot:

- For Command Prompt: [Create a Bootable USB Flash Drive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200124.aspx)
- For 3rd party software: [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool)